# How to create a secure password for a Java keystore?

Tags: passwords, cryptography

What would be the recommended approach (industry standard) for generating a password for a Java keystore that contains TLS certificates? In the event that the keystore is obtained, an attacker would have unlimited time to brute force the password.

Would a UUID be the best approach? What is the best way to easily generate a pseudorandom one from the command line if so?

Comment: If the keystone contains TLS keys then it will be used by a server and servers usually start automatically without user interaction. There it doesn't matter how secure the password is because you have to save it somewhere so that the server can start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A password with 256 bits of entropy is more than enough to withstand even the most well-resourced brute-force attacks.  See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1145/how-much-would-it-cost-in-u-s-dollars-to-brute-force-a-256-bit-key-in-a-year for some interesting reading on this subject.

The command below will produce a random password with 256 bits of entropy:

```
head /dev/urandom | sha256sum
```